# Dante - Socks4 Configuration

Tags: socks, dante

We have application it supports SOCKS4 proxy support and we would like to test it.  So we have installed dante in SUSE and it is configured for SOCKS5 by default. Is there any option where we can enable SOCKS4 support?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [man sockd.conf](http://www.inet.no/dante/doc/1.2.x/sockd.conf.5.html), by default, it supports both of v4 and v5. But you can specify only v4 by using `proxyprotocol` option, something like this:

```
route {
    from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0 via: 127.0.0.1 port = 1080 
    protocol: tcp
    proxyprotocol: socks_v4
    command: connect
    method: none
}
```